# How to convert from string array to sortedSet

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, vb.net, type-conversion

I need to extract(the easy part) a list of integers given through an array of strings gotten from:  someString.split(separator)  What I need is to put that resulting array(string) in a sortedSet How do I convert that? I've tried different things.

the current code is in VB

```
Dim _ports As New SortedSet(Of Integer) = Array.ConvertAll(portString.Split(","),Integer.Parse())
```

I've tried this but is not correct.
I know that is simple to iterate though every single item and put it into the sortedSet but, is there any way to do it directly.

Comment: You need to use foreach loop to add items to sortedsets. It's the easiest way. Let me know If you need the loop.

Comment: i know that part, it's just iterating through every single item in the array and add it to the set:    for each i in array..... What i want is to know any way to do it directly like shown above in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# - `Enumerable.Select` will do conversion of string to integer if you pass `int.Parse` to it.

```
var resultingArray = new SortedSet<int>(portString.Split(',').Select(int.Parse));
```

Comment: would i get an array or a sortedSet?

Comment: @Fernando - fixed - original was creating Array with `ToArray`, for `SortedSet<int>` just pass resulting enumerable to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

So, translating what Alexei Levenkov wrote to VB would be:

```
Dim resultingArray = New SortedSet(Of Integer)(portString.Split(","c).Select(AddressOf Integer.Parse))
```